# Ethernet keeps connecting and dropping

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, intel

I'm trying to set up Ubuntu for the first time and I'm getting a weird problem with the network.

My network card is onboard the CROSSHAIR-VI. It's an Intel i211 I believe. I've downloaded the latest drivers from [here on the Intel downloads site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/64403/Intel-Ethernet-Controller-I211-Series), and copied them via usb stick to the new Ubuntu machine. I followed the instructions in the README and was able to `make install`, and find the resulting file: `/lib/modules/.../updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb.ko`

I then tried

```
sudo rmmod igb
```

and

```
sudo modprobe igb
```

After that I was hoping it would just connect to the DHCP on its own. It does seem to do so, but as before it then drops the connections after about 0.5 seconds.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from a USB stick.

Comment: Glad you found the source of your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was bad ethernet cable. I swapped the cable out and now everything works.